# How to perform multiple subsets of data in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I have 300 variables (columns) taken at 10 timepoints (rows), for each variable at any given timepoint I have temperature values A and F. So on my dataframe I have 2 rows for timepoint 1 for A+F and so on

here is my reproducible example

```
Timepoint <- c('1','1','2','2','3','3')
Temperature <- c('A','F','A','F','A','F')
Cholesterol <- c('1','2','3','2','3','4')

data.frame(Timepoint,Temperature,Cholesterol)
```

This is a sample of my actual data

```
 structure(list(Timepoint = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
  5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 25L, 25L), 
     Temperature = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
     1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "F"), class = "factor"), Concentration.of.chylomicrons = c(1.29e-11, 
    1.25e-11, 1.02e-11, 1.1e-11, 1.08e-11, 1.3e-11, 1.28e-11, 
    1.26e-11, 1.06e-11, 1.32e-11, 8.85e-12, 1.21e-11, 8.83e-12, 
    1.08e-11, 1.35e-11, 1.12e-11, 8.99e-12, 1.08e-11, 9.55e-12, 
    1.04e-11, 0, 1.01e-11), Total.lipids = c(0.00268, 0.0026, 
    0.00208, 0.00225, 0.00222, 0.0027, 0.00268, 0.0026, 0.00219, 
    0.00273, 0.0018, 0.00247, 0.00179, 0.00221, 0.00276, 0.00229, 
     0.00182, 0.00222, 0.00195, 0.00212, 0, 0.00204), Phospholipids = c(0.000224, 
    0.000223, 0.000145, 0.00016, 0.000157, 0.000211, 0.00023, 
    0.000211, 0.000165, 0.000224, 0.000109, 0.00018, 0.000113, 
    0.000163, 0.000175, 0.000177, 0.000122, 0.000173, 0.000127, 
    0.000156, 0, 0.000138)), .Names = c("Timepoint", "Temperature", 
"Concentration.of.chylomicrons", "Total.lipids", "Phospholipids"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

I would like to draw a line graph to show how each variable varies with time. On this line graph I would like the A and B lines to be drawn

I have managed to do this with the following r code

```
plot(DATA$Timepoint[DATA$Temperature=="F"],DATA$variable[DATA$Temperature=="F"])

lines(DATA$Timepoint[DATA$Temperature=="F"],DATA$Cvariable[TempMline$Temperature=="A"])
```

This gives plots how the variable alters with time, with a separate line for each temperature A + F.

I am trying to write a loop command to draw a graph for each variable, although I'm having trouble with using [] to subset data and also write the loop command

Here is my attempt

```
lnames <- names(DATA)
classes<-sapply(DATA,class)

for(name in lnames[classes == 'numeric']) {

 plot(DATA$Timepoint[DATA$Temperature=="F"],DATA$[,name][DATA$Temperature=="F"])
 lines(DATA$Timepoint[DATA$Temperature=="F"],DATA$[,name][TempMline$Temperature=="A"]) }
```

Comment: Please read this, and  upload reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @M.Siwik how can I upload my dataframe?

Comment: Just dput(name of your data frame) in console and copy/paste it's here.

Comment: @M.Siwik, I have done both I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I only show the last graph since that's the end of the loop. If you're using RStudio, you can just toggle the left/right arrow key in the plot viewer.

[image]

Here's the code for the plotting and loop:

```
# subset based on temperatures A and F
a_df <- subset(df, Temperature == "A")
f_df <- subset(df, Temperature == "F")

# loop from columns 3:5 (or for the number of variables you have)
for (i in 3:5) {
      plot(a_df[, 1], 
           a_df[, i], 
           type = "l",
           ylab = colnames(a_df[i]),
           xlab = "Timepoint",
           lwd = 2,
           col = "blue")
      lines(f_df[, 1],
            f_df[, i],
            type = "l",
            lwd = 2,
            col = "red")
      legend("bottomleft", 
             col = c("blue", "red"), 
             legend = c("Temperature A", "Temperature F"), 
             lwd = 2,
             y.intersp = 0.5,
             bty = "n")
}
```

Comment: Words cannot express my gratitude. Many thanks for you kind help

Comment: Quick question certain data points on the graphs are outside the plot area. How can I adjust the scale for the graph to ensure that all points plotted?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I believe it's `xlim = c(x, y) and ylim = c(x, y)`. `xlim` sets the range that your x-axis can take.